Distribution upgrade to 24.04 LTS leads to GUI programs and complete system hanging
Did the distribution upgrade to 24.04 via sudo do-release-upgrade, but ended with the error “Oh no – something went wrong”.
Restarting, going to a console and using the following commands allowed me at least to start Ubuntu 24.04 and have the desktop shown:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo reboot

But opening GUI applications like the Gnome "Files" or "Software" lead to the system hanging (the windows opened and after a few seconds everything freezes - just mouse movements are possible, but nothing can be clicked; console cannot be opended).
Additional steps taken:

Internet access did not work, could be restored by adding nameservers in
/etc/resolv.conf.
Reinstall of gnome-control-center, nautilus, and
ubuntu-desktop did not help - once I open one of the critical GUI applications like "Files" the freezing re-occurs.

Anything short of a complete re-install that I can do ?

If the desktop is misbehaving, sometimes you just need to re-install it - sudo apt -y install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop - or whichever distribution you are using kubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, etc...

@user535733 The apt term.log showed nothing specific (a few warnings with non-empty  directories which could not be deleted and some parsing errors related to a python3 package). The journalctl has on the day I started the distribution upgrade thousands of lines "too many open files"; when I start the system now there are error messages "kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nv84_xuc00f failed with error -2".  Also "Failed to start casper-md5check.service." and systemd "Failed to start zsys-user-savestate.service".

@AnthonyK I had tried the re-install of the Ubuntu Desktop already to no avail (as already stated in my original description of the error).

After the distribution upgrade there were a few crashes related to "gstreamer1.0" ("gst-plugin-scanner crashed with SIGABRT [...]") and "gnome-shell" ("gnome-shell crashed with SIGTRAP [...]") but they did not cause the system to freeze directly.   The freezing still occurs and seems not to leave a trace in journal / syslog or a crash log.

Please edit your question to add new information or clarifications instead of using comments. Comments are not intended for conversation. When your question has enough information to be answerable, somebody is likely to answer it.

@ansgar: apologies - I missed that part.  What I can add is that I've only ever had success on a server running the do-release-upgrade.  The one and only time I ran it on a desktop (upgrading my first install of 8.04 to 10.04), it broke completely the desktop completely and hence never used it again.  I only do fresh installs.  I learnt to never have /home and /opt as part of the root system for this reason.
